# How can I add video dimensions to video file tooltips?

Tags: video, windows-registry, regedit, dimensions

Hi there I would like to add some extra info to my video file [tooltips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooltip) on my computer. How do I add **video dimensions** to my video file [tooltips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooltip)??? AKA the little popup that appears when you hover over a file. I edited the tooltip for MP3 files before by following this TUT: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=vUyZXYTn[image: Video File Tooltip]

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out the solution on my own lol... Probably shoulda tried this before I asked the question but anyways here is the answer I came up with that works! Okay so all you do is:

1. Open regedit
2. Navigate to Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations
3. Navigate to the video file keys you want to edit the tooltip info for. Eg. (.avi, .mp4, .wmv, etc...)
4. To make sure it is a video file extension look under the file key "PreviewDetails" and make sure ***System.Video.FrameHeight** AND ***System.Video.FrameWidth** are listed somewhere in the file key.
5. Also make sure the "InfoTip" key says: **prop:System.ItemType;System.Size;System.Media.Duration;System.OfflineAvailability**
6. Change the InfoTip key to: **prop:System.ItemType;System.Size;System.Media.Duration;*System.Video.FrameHeight;*System.Video.FrameWidth;System.OfflineAvailability** and as you can see it adds the *System.Video.FrameHeight AND *System.Video.FrameWidth info...

I hope this helps anyone else looking to add extra info to their video tooltips. This method can be used to add other info as well. All you need to do is look at the "FullDetails" key and copy certain sections into the InfoTip key. Other info you can add in more than likely isn't listed but I unfortunately don't know what that would be...